Book recommendation for stochastic integral wrt local martingales
I am looking for a book (or a chapter of a book) for stochastic integral wrt local martingales.
The book should contain a rigourous introduction to the definition. It should also contain proofs for the properties of the integral process (most importantly, the local martingale property).
Background: I have read the book "Introduction to Stochastic Integration" by Hui-Hsiung Kuo, where integral wrt Brownian motion and martingales are introduced. I am familar with martingale theory.
[Update]
It is hoped that the book first defines the integral wrt simple step processes, and then extends to general processes.

Personally, I recommend Chap. 3 of Stochastic Calculus by Michael R. Tehranchi. It uses the same language as the book by Hui-Hsiung Kuo, and extends the intgeral to local martingales and semi-martingale.

I would suggest, that you consider "Brownian Motion, Martingales, and Stochastic Calculus  " by Le Gall. He does not use the Reisz representation theorem to define the stochastic integral, he does the construction with Riemann sums, similar as in the definition of the Riemann integral. For me this was easier to understand when I got in touch with it the first time.

I'm a big fan of "Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion" by Revuz and Yor.  They define the stochastic integral using the Reisz representation theorem, then show it agrees with the definition a lot of other books use as a limit of Riemann sums.  It's nice because using Reisz makes the local martingale property essentially part of the definition of the stochastic integral.
